# Проблемы с self в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Что такое self в данном случаем? Ведь self это ссылка на экземпляр класса, то есть, например, `a = Test()` self ссылается на a, мы можем передать аргументы a и посмотреть их с помощью **dict**. А тут что происходит?

```
class Test():
  def __init__(self):
    self.t = "test"

print(Test())
print(Test().__dict__)
```

Я предположил, что класс создает какой-то "невидимый" для нас экземпляр и записывает туда аргументы. И с каждым новым вызовом класса создаются разные экземпляры.

```
print(Test()) # <__main__.Test object at 0x7ff9b57c0630>
print(Test().__dict__) # {'t': 'test'}
print(Test()) # <__main__.Test object at 0x7ff9b57c04a8>
print(Test().__dict__) # {'t': 'test'}
```

Но видимо нет. Ибо если добавить третий вызов.

```
print(Test()) # <__main__.Test object at 0x7f0976f064a8>
print(Test().__dict__) #{'t': 'test'}
print(Test()) # <__main__.Test object at 0x7f0976f064a8>
print(Test().__dict__) # {'t': 'test'}
print(Test()) # <__main__.Test object at 0x7f0976f064a8>
print(Test().__dict__) # {'t': 'test'}
```

Происходит вот такая странная ситуация. Так что же тут происходит, черт возьми?

Comment: Что-то я не понял суть вопроса. Тут то же самое: `self` ссылается на экземпляр класса, который вы создали вызовом `Test()`. Но так как вы не положили их ни в какую постоянную переменную, эти экземпляры уничтожаются сразу же после завершения работы принтов (или не совсем сразу же, но это зависит от текущего настроения сборщика мусора)

Comment: В `a = Test()` - a - всего лишь ссылка на вновь созданный объект. Этот объект существует и без присваивания. Именно на него и ссылается self

Comment: «Происходит вот такая странная ситуация» — что странного? Если вас смущает одинаковый «at» адрес, то питон просто переиспользует освободившуюся память для создания нового объекта, ничего странного

Comment: Сохраните ссылки, которые возвращает `Test()` в переменные, и увидите разные `object at`.

Comment: `print(Test(), Test(), Test())` - на момент вызова print все 3 экземпляра должны существовать, адреса должны быть разными)

Comment: Для того, что бы понять, что с одним и тем же `at` у вас создаются разные экземпляры, сохраняйте в свойстве `t` не константную строку, а случайное число.